# Video sometimes upside down when uploading to Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

In my app, I record video, and capture photo for all orientation. I tried to upload my video on youtube and share link on Facebook, and everything was good. But now I cant use youtube. So, I start upload my video on Facebook directly with Facebook SDK. But, depends on what orientation was during video record, video sometimes uploaded upside down. So, whats wrong with my method.

```
- (void)shareFBVideo {

Facebook *facebook = ((FSAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]).facebook;
((FSAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]).shareUrl = activityController.storeURL;
NSArray *permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"offline_access", nil];
[facebook authorize:permissions];
```

}

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

NSData *attachmentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:shareUrl];
//    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               NSLocalizedString(@"title", nil), @"title", 
                               NSLocalizedString(@"description", nil), @"description", 
                               @"Test file", @"file",
                               attachmentData, @"Video.mp4",
                               nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

}

It my first practise with Facebook SDK, so I hope in simple error) I will appreciate your help!